# How can I change a source folder to a test source folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, build

How can I define a folder, in eclipse, as a test folder?  On my machine, the test folder `/src/test` shows up correctly, with the test green test folder icon.

[image]

However, one a coworker's computer it shows as a source package. How do I assign/update this value?

Comment: Your coworker does not seem to be importing the project correctly; this will happen automatically on a correct import. Use File→Import→Existing Maven projects.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I think we tried it both ways.  We are using mvn eclsipe:eclipse.  Not sure why it only seems to work once in a while.

Comment: `mvn eclipse:eclipse` has been obsolete for over 10 years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to go to Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path

Then in the Source tab, you choose "Add Folder" and select that src/test/java, once it is added to your sources you double click where it says "Contains test sources"